# Wordpress: Visual Composer stuck on loading

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Today I have installed Klaus Theme 1.5.2.Everything goes good but, then I tried to edit a Page and add Visual Composer elements the loading bar keeps loading. I have installed this theme with WPBackery on several servers and WP installments but same error.The plugin version is 1.5.2 and it can't be changed.
Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as of today (01-May-2016) Klaus Theme's Updated Version is – 1.6.2.1 and your Theme is way out dated.Old VC elements in New browsers will often not work and specially if the theme is downloaded from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Current stable version of `Visual Composer` is  `4.11.2` and your installed version is outdated one as you are using `1.5.2` version. Update your plugin with latest plugin and your issue will be resolved. For further information about Visual Composer visit https://vc.wpbakery.com/